# Running application in background with progress notification

Tags: android, android-asynctask, androidx

I'm doing a download process using asyncTask over a webview so that downloading process will be happening until the app gets closed. Again when user opens the app, the downloading process continues. I tried running it in a backgroundService and i started the service once the app is stopped. The problem is service is getting started but when i close the app, the service stops. I also tried displaying notification while service is running but still when i close the app, service will be killed. I referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126979/cannot-keep-android-service-alive-after-app-is-closed). Kindly suggest me something where it solves me the problem and that should work starting from Android lollipop till the latest.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that a foreground service is the answer
like in the link just additional with a notification channel

First check how to start the service with:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this@MainActivity, YourService::class.java);
            
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) 
        startForegroundService(intent);
    else 
        startService(intent);
```

Then from Service create a Notification channel before you setup the notification:

```
     private NotificationManager createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID, "NAME", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
            return manager;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Finally after that call:

```
Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
startForeground(1, notification);
```

Now should the notification be alive as long as your app is

If this doesn't work write to your registered service in manifest this

```
<service
     android:name=".YourService"
     android:stopWithTask="true" />
```