# Issue running a background task in android when the app is killed

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, telephony

This is in relation to the question [How to run a background task in android when the app is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72301378/how-to-run-a-background-task-in-android-when-the-app-is-killed) which I posted a few days ago.

After reading some blogs (e.g [this](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124)) and code (of [telephony](https://pub.dev/packages/telephony)) I have done some coding. My requirement is to show the user some sort of notification when a call is received, even when my app is not running (much like the **Truecaller** app in android). I am posting the code below.

`callback_dispatcher.dart`

```
const String HANDLE_INCOMING_CALL_BG = "handleIncomingCallBg";
const String INCOMING_CALL_BG_INITIALIZED = "incomingCallBgInitialized";
const String INCOMING_CALL_BG_INIT_SERVICE = "incomingCallBgInitService";
const String backgroundChannelId = "background_channel";
const String foregroundChannelId = "foreground_channel";

void callback_dispatcher() {
    const MethodChannel _backgroundChannel = MethodChannel(backgroundChannelId);
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    _backgroundChannel.setMethodCallHandler((MethodCall call) =>
    methodCallHandler(call));
    _backgroundChannel.invokeMethod<void>(INCOMING_CALL_BG_INITIALIZED);
}

Future<dynamic> methodCallHandler(MethodCall call) async {
    if(call.method == HANDLE_INCOMING_CALL_BG) {
        final CallbackHandle _handle =
        CallbackHandle.fromRawHandle(call.arguments['handle']);
        final Function _handlerFunc = PluginUtilities.getCallbackFromHandle(_handle)!;
        try {
            await _handlerFunc(call.arguments['message']);
        } catch(e) {
            print('Unable to handle incoming call in background');
            print(e);
        }
    }
    return Future<void>.value();
}

void handleBgMsg(String msg) {
    debugPrint("[handleBgMsg] incoming call number : " + msg);
    // notification to user
}
```

`background_incoming_call.dart`

```
typedef BgMessageHandler(String msg);

class BackgroundIncomingCall {
    MethodChannel? foregroundChannel;

    Future<void> initialize(BgMessageHandler onBgMessage) async {
        foregroundChannel = const MethodChannel(foregroundChannelId);
        final CallbackHandle? bgSetupHandle = 
        PluginUtilities.getCallbackHandle(callback_dispatcher);
        final CallbackHandle? bgMsgHandle = 
        PluginUtilities.getCallbackHandle(onBgMessage);
        await foregroundChannel?.invokeMethod<bool>(
            INCOMING_CALL_BG_INIT_SERVICE,
            <String, dynamic> {
            'bgSetupHandle': bgSetupHandle?.toRawHandle(),
            'bgMsgHandle': bgMsgHandle?.toRawHandle()
            }
        );
    }
}
```

In `main.dart` I am initializing `BackgroundIncomingCall().initialize(handleBgMsg);`.

On the Android part I have created a `BroadcastReceiver` as follows (the code mostly from the aforementioned **Telephony** package).

```
public class CallEventReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements
    MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler {
private static final String TAG = "[TEST]";
private static final int NUMBER_LEN = 10;

public static String INCOMING_CALL_BG_INITIALIZED = "incomingCallBgInitialized";
public static String INCOMING_CALL_BG_INIT_SERVICE = "incomingCallBgInitService";
public static String SETUP_HANDLE = "bgSetupHandle";
public static String MESSAGE_HANDLE = "bgMsgHandle";
public static String BG_INCOMING_CALL_CHANNEL_ID = "background_channel";
public static String FG_INCOMING_CALL_CHANNEL_ID = "foreground_channel";
public static String HANDLE_INCOMING_CALL_BG = "handleIncomingCallBg";
public static String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "incomingCallSharedPrefBg";
public static String SHARED_PREF_BG_INCOMING_CALL_HANDLE = "incomingCallSharedPrefBgHandle";
public static String SHARED_PREFS_BACKGROUND_SETUP_HANDLE = "backgroundSetupHandle";

private Activity activity = null;

/* for background isolate*/
private Context appContext = null;
private AtomicBoolean isIsolateRunning = new AtomicBoolean(false);
private List<String> bgIncomingCallQueue = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
private MethodChannel bgIncomingCallChannel = null;;
private MethodChannel fgIncomingCallChannel = null;;
private FlutterLoader flutterLoader = null;
private FlutterEngine bgFlutterEngine = null;
private Long bgIncomingCallHandle = null;
/* END */

public CallEventReceiver() {}

public CallEventReceiver(Activity activity) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull MethodChannel.Result result) {
    if(call.method.equals(INCOMING_CALL_BG_INITIALIZED)) {
        if(appContext != null) {
            onChannelInitialized(appContext);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Application context is not set");
        }
    } else if(call.method.equals(INCOMING_CALL_BG_INIT_SERVICE)) {
        if(appContext != null) {
            if(call.hasArgument(SETUP_HANDLE) && call.hasArgument(MESSAGE_HANDLE)) {
                Long setupHandle = call.<Long>argument(SETUP_HANDLE);
                Long msgHandle = call.<Long>argument(MESSAGE_HANDLE);
                if (setupHandle == null || msgHandle == null) {
                    result.error("ILLEGAL_ARGS", "Setup handle or message handle is missing", null);
                    return;
                }
                setBgSetupHandle(appContext, setupHandle);
                setBgMessageHandle(appContext, msgHandle);
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Application context is not set");
        }
    } else {
        result.notImplemented();
    }
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.appContext = context;
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "[CallEventHandler] Receiver start");
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            if(incomingNumber != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "[CallEventHandler] Incoming number : " + incomingNumber);
                if(incomingNumber.length() > NUMBER_LEN) {
                    incomingNumber = incomingNumber.substring(incomingNumber.length() - NUMBER_LEN, incomingNumber.length());
                    Log.i(TAG, "[CallEventHandler] Incoming number after : " + incomingNumber);
                    processIncomingCall(context, incomingNumber);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void setBgMessageHandle(Context ctx, Long handle) {
    bgIncomingCallHandle = handle;
    SharedPreferences pref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    pref.edit().putLong(SHARED_PREF_BG_INCOMING_CALL_HANDLE, handle).apply();
}

public void setBgSetupHandle(Context ctx, Long setupBgHandle) {
    SharedPreferences pref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    pref.edit().putLong(SHARED_PREFS_BACKGROUND_SETUP_HANDLE, setupBgHandle).apply();
}

private void processIncomingCall(Context ctx, String incomingNumber) {
    boolean isForeground = isAppForeground(ctx);
    Log.i(TAG, "[processIncomingCall] is app in foreground : " + isForeground);
    if (isForeground) {
        processIncomingCallInForeground(incomingNumber);
    } else {
        processIncomingCallInBackground(ctx, incomingNumber);
    }
}

private void processIncomingCallInBackground(Context ctx, String incomingNumber) {
    if(!isIsolateRunning.get()) {
        init(ctx);
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Long bgCallbackHandle = sharedPref.getLong(SHARED_PREFS_BACKGROUND_SETUP_HANDLE, 0);
        startBackgroundIsolate(ctx, bgCallbackHandle);
        bgIncomingCallQueue.add(incomingNumber);
    } else {
        executeDartCallbackInBgIsolate(ctx, incomingNumber);
    }
}

private void processIncomingCallInForeground(String incomingNumber) {
    Log.i(TAG, "[processIncomingCallInFg] incoming number : " + incomingNumber);
    if(activity != null) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(eventSink != null) {
                    eventSink.success(incomingNumber);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

private void onChannelInitialized(Context ctx) {
    isIsolateRunning.set(true);
    synchronized(bgIncomingCallQueue) {
        Iterator<String> it = bgIncomingCallQueue.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            executeDartCallbackInBgIsolate(ctx, it.next());
        }
        bgIncomingCallQueue.clear();
    }
}

private void init(Context ctx) {
    FlutterInjector flutterInjector = FlutterInjector.instance();
    flutterLoader = flutterInjector.flutterLoader();
    flutterLoader.startInitialization(ctx);
}

private void executeDartCallbackInBgIsolate(Context ctx, String incomingNumber) {
    if(bgIncomingCallChannel == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("background channel is not initialized");
    }

    if(bgIncomingCallHandle == null) {
        bgIncomingCallHandle = getBgMessageHandle(ctx);
    }
    HashMap<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    args.put("handle", bgIncomingCallHandle);
    args.put("message", incomingNumber);
    bgIncomingCallChannel.invokeMethod(HANDLE_INCOMING_CALL_BG, args);
}

private Long getBgMessageHandle(Context ctx) {
    return ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getLong(SHARED_PREF_BG_INCOMING_CALL_HANDLE, 0);
}

private void startBackgroundIsolate(Context ctx, Long callbackHandle) {
    String appBundlePath = flutterLoader.findAppBundlePath();
    FlutterCallbackInformation cbInfo = FlutterCallbackInformation.
            lookupCallbackInformation(callbackHandle);

    DartExecutor.DartCallback dartEntryPoint =
            new DartExecutor.DartCallback(ctx.getAssets(), appBundlePath, cbInfo);
    bgFlutterEngine = new FlutterEngine(ctx, flutterLoader, new FlutterJNI());
    bgFlutterEngine.getDartExecutor().executeDartCallback(dartEntryPoint);

    bgIncomingCallChannel = new MethodChannel(bgFlutterEngine.getDartExecutor(),
            BG_INCOMING_CALL_CHANNEL_ID);
    bgIncomingCallChannel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
}

private boolean isAppForeground(Context ctx) {
    KeyguardManager keyGuardManager = (KeyguardManager) ctx.
            getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    if(keyGuardManager.isKeyguardLocked()) {
        return false;
    }
    int pid = Process.myPid();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) ctx.
            getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> list =
            activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for(ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo proc : list) {
        if(pid == proc.pid) {
            return proc.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

In my `AndroidManifest.xml` I am registering the broadcast receiver

```
<receiver android:name="org.cdot.diu.handler.CallEventReceiver" android:exported="true">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
       </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Now If I run my app and minimize it, the `handleBgMsg` is called successfully. Since no print or debug message is shown in terminal when I kill the app, I am sending an SMS to me using Telephony package, which is sent successfully when the app is minimized. But it does not work if I kill the application, no SMS is sent. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. My guess is that the Broadcast Receiver is killed when the app is killed. However, in the **telephony** package there is nothing to indicate that special care is done to keep the receiver alive when the app is killed.

Comment: If you are building a calling app, did you see: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged

Comment: No I am not trying to build a calling app. My main motivation is to see how these background task are done when the app is not running, in flutter. For testing I am receiveing the call events in my `BroadcastReceiver` which is working as it is. The telephony package also gets incoming messages when the app is not running.