# on minimizing, the app is not searching for GPS

Tags: android, google-maps, android-gps

I am making an Android App which includes google map. While minimizing the app no longer searches for GPS. Is there a way to turn on the gps for the app all the time even when the map is minimized?

Comment: To run your GPS location continuously use service class. [Look at this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21532572/9254960).   If u want the app run after app close. run the service continuously else, kill the service at `onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)` inside service class with `stopSelf()` method.

Comment: Sounds like it will work, I am going to apply this and coming back to you with an answer

Answer (score 0):

@Sudipta for prior Oreo version you have to use jobscheduler.

> 1. Create a JobScheduler class

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class JobSchedulerClass extends JobService {

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {

        Intent startService = new Intent(this, YourServiceClass.class);
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, startService);
        return false;
    }

}
```

> 2. Call the service class and service class based the the version of device running

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(11, new ComponentName(context, JobSchedulerClass.class))
                .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(false)
                .setMinimumLatency(100)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_NONE)
                .build();
        assert jobScheduler != null;
        jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
    } else {
        Intent startService = new Intent(context, YourServiceClass.class);
        context.startService(startService);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, for time being, i have used my local class names in the project. replace MainActivity.class to your service class.... updated the post. please check now