# How to keep running app even app is close in react-native

Tags: react-native

*I want my app run even app close. or just run  when location coordinates changed.*

*I used appState but it doesnt help me  because it works just when appState change.*

*also I used `react-native-background-task` but it runs every 7m30s*

**I use this now but it doesnt help me too. what should I do ?**

```
location(){
  this.watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
    (position) => {

      console.log(position.coords.latitude);
       var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
       var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

      this.setState({latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude});
    },
    (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
    { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000},
  );
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.location()
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchId);
}
```

Comment: Android and/or iOS?

Comment: Just in android.

Comment: You need to create an Android unbound service, but you will need to write native  code for this

Comment: How do i do this. Any help ?

Comment: This link may help, but I have no experience with this myself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441232/keep-location-service-alive-when-the-app-is-closed